# "Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError" when importing WordPress pages with Elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, import, importerror, elementor

I'm developing a custom WordPress theme and encountering an issue while importing pages using Elementor. I'm using a free version of Elementor, and I have successfully exported the pages using the following code:

```
$pages = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'page', 'numberposts' => -1) );
$exported_data['pages'] = array();
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    $page_data = array(
        'ID' => $page->ID,
        'post_title' => $page->post_title,
        'post_content' => $page->post_content,
        'meta' => get_post_meta($page->ID),
        'is_elementor' => (get_post_meta($page->ID, '_elementor_edit_mode', true) === 'builder'),
        '_elementor_data' => get_post_meta($page->ID, '_elementor_data', true)
    );
    $exported_data['pages'][] = $page_data;
}
```

However, when I try to import the pages using the following code:

```
$exported_pages = $imported_data['pages'];
$page_id_mapping = array();
if (isset($exported_pages)) {
    foreach ($exported_pages as $page_data) {
        // ...
        // Code to create the page and set metadata
        // ...
        // Using Elementor
        if ($page_data['is_elementor']) {
            $elementor_data = array();
            if (isset($page_data['_elementor_data'])) {

                        $decoded_data = json_decode($page_data['_elementor_data'], true);
                        $elementor_data = $decoded_data[0];
            }
            update_post_meta($page_id, '_elementor_data', $elementor_data);
            update_post_meta($page_id, '_elementor_edit_mode', 'builder');
        }
    }
}
```

I receive the error "Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Elementor\Core\Page_Assets\Loader::enable_assets(): Argument #1 ($assets_data) must be of type array". This error seems to be caused by the enable_assets() call in Elementor.

I have already verified that the value of _elementor_data is valid JSON, and I have correctly decoded the associative array. I'm not sure what could be causing this error or how to resolve it.

```
_elementor_data decode:
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string 'd9e7f92' (length=7)
      'elType' => string 'section' (length=7)
      'settings' => 
        array (size=10)
          'layout' => string 'full_width' (length=10)
          'height' => string 'full' (length=4)
          'content_position' => string 'middle' (length=6)
          'overflow' => string 'hidden' (length=6)
          'background_background' => string 'classic' (length=7)
          'background_image' => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          'background_position' => string 'center center' (length=13)
          'background_repeat' => string 'no-repeat' (length=9)
          'background_size' => string 'cover' (length=5)
          'css_classes' => string 'hero' (length=4)
      'elements' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
      'isInner' => boolean false
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue while importing WordPress pages with Elementor? What could be the possible solutions or alternatives to properly handle the import of Elementor data in a custom theme?

Thank you in advance for the help!